# AFNetworking lib not loading data in offline mode in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am developing a content reading app in which some data is displayed in a tale view and respective detail views.

I have already completed the app but there is a small bug.

I am using AFNetworking library for online data load and offline caching.
I have defined caching policy as described by following code:

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
if ([reach isReachable]) {
    // Reachable

    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval:60.0];

}
else{

    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad
                                  timeoutInterval:60.0];
}
```

But, I am having a small problem that if I load some data online and then turn off the internet connection and close the app, and afterwords if I restart the app again in offline mode, the cached data should load but it is not happening.

I also have tried changing the caching policies as defined in [this link](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/).

app deployment target : iOS 6.0

 devices : universal

 xcode version : 6.1

 AFNetworking lib version : 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of the code you posted and just set the request cache policy to `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`.

As it stands, you're currently making a synchronous reachability query on every request. Either that or worse—it's returning immediately, but always returning before a real reachability state can be determined.

Comment: thanks. but i explicitly need to load data from the server if the device is online and load data from local cache if the device is off line. but I am not able to achieve that state. Could you please explain a bit more what you are trying to say.

Comment: hey Matt, I am waiting for your reply